# Trace formula of symmetric representation in Fulton and Harris Representation Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I am reading Fulton and Harris' "Representation Theory" and I have
some problems to understand a construction in Chapter §6.1 on pg. 77:

Let $\rho: G \to \text{GL}(V)$ a complex finite representation,
$k= \dim_{\mathbb{C}} V$.
For any partition $\lambda$ of a number $d$ the *Schur functor*
induces a new representation $\mathcal{S}_{\lambda}(V)$. To any representation $\rho$ one can associate a *trace
character* $\chi_{\rho}: G \to \mathbb{C}$. Let denote by
$\chi_{\mathcal{S}_{\lambda}(V)}$ the trace of $\mathcal{S}_{\lambda}(V)$.

Let's consider the symmetric representation $\mathcal{S}_{(d)}(V)=
\text{Sym}^d V$. In (6.1) is claimed that there is formula

$$  \chi_{\mathcal{S}_{\lambda}(V)}(g)=  H_d(x_1(g),..., x_k(g))  $$

where $H_d(x_1,..., x_k)$ is the complete symmetric polynomial
of degree $d$ and $x_1(g),..., x_k(g)$ are the eigenvalues of $g$ on $V$.

But not every endomorphism $\rho(g)$ is diagonalizable,
so why for every $g$ there
exist exactly $k$ eigenvalues $x_1(g),..., x_k(g)$? Or are these
"eigenvalues" here actually the entries of the diagonal of the Jordan form
of $\rho(g) \in \text{GL}(V)$?

Comment: If $G$ is finite or at least that every element of $G$ has finite order, then $\rho(g)$ is indeed diagonalizable: indeed, if $n\geq 1$ is such $g^n=1$, then $X^n-1$ is an annihilating polynomial of $\rho(g)$. But $X^n-1$ has only complex simple roots.

Comment: @GreginGre: a good catch but it not seems that the autors assumed in this chapter $G$ to be finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ does not need to be finite and you do not need diagonalizability. The eigenvalues $x_1(g), \dots x_k(g)$ here are being listed with their *algebraic* multiplicities; that's why there are always $k$ of them, and this is the only way to do it that produces a continuous function on the RHS.